# How do I grant permission to another user for my Google+ product / brand page?

Tags: google-plus, permissions

I have recently created a page for my workplace in Google Plus, using my Google account. I would like my colleagues to also be able to log in to this page to manage and update it.

How do I give another user access to a page I have created?

When I go to [Google+ Page management](https://plus.google.com/pages/manage), it says:

> Shown below is the list of Google+ pages you have either created or
>   **have been given access to**. You can view the page, edit it or change its settings.

which firmly implies that it's possible.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Google+ page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/101560853443212199687/posts/BbbJc6tBo81): "+Dennis Troper wanted to update you and say we are already working on **multi-admin support**, ownership transfer and page analytics." (emphasis mine)

So it's not quite ready.

Comment: Added about a week ago: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/12/google-few-big-improvements-before-new.html