# Multiple admins for a Google+ brand page

Tags: google, google-plus, google-plus-pages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I grant permission to another user for my Google+ product / brand page?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20537/how-do-i-grant-permission-to-another-user-for-my-google-product-brand-page)

Is there any way for a Google+ brand page to have more than one admin? I'm sure I can share the Gmail account but I'd rather not do this as we'll be having multiple users from different offices.

Comment: Looks like the multi-admins feature is coming soon: https://plus.google.com/105912973864602608032/posts/iUbF9vBEuSb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently that's not possible at the moment, but is being worked on. Sources:

- http://www.smallbusinesstechtips.com/small-business-website-strategies/google-plus-business-pages-lack-multiple-admin-feature/
- http://www.buzzmaven.com/2011/11/no-multiple-admins-in-google-plus-pages-for-businesses-seriously.html